# React Firebase "FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline."

Tags: reactjs, firebase

the data loading good, but when I keep the page for half hour without any actions and then trying to load data without refreshing page - I'm getting this error. I've found similar issue here and added firebase.firestore().enablePersistence(). It didn't help. The other weird observation, even when the data loading successfully I'm often observe in network this error [image][image]

My firebase config:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC**********1vY38Q",
  authDomain: "****.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://********",
  projectId: "myproject",
  storageBucket: "****.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "209382989",
  appId: "1:1**********ceda27",
  measurementId: "G*****B96",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence();
export const db = firebase.firestore();

export default firebase;
```

My request:

```
import firebase, { db } from "./firebase.config";

const getData = async (db, collection, docId) => {
  const data = await db.collection(collection).doc(docId.toString()).get();
  return { data: data.data()?.history.map((con) => ({ ...con, profileId: docId, names: {} })) || [], docId };
};

export const getCollectionData = async (collection, docIdArray) => {
  try {
    await firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("in promise");
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
        if (user) {
          try {
            const data = await Promise.all((docIdArray.map((docId) => getData(db, collection, docId))));
            resolve(data);
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
        } else {
          console.log("user is signed out");
          // User is signed out
          // ...
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log.apply(error);
  }
};
```

after page reloading it works fine. 403 error sometimes dissappeared sometimes not. Does anybody faced something similar?

Comment: check for your proxy

Comment: I'm not using proxy for this request

Comment: and I've added both domains in firebase console (localhost that I'm using in development, and other public domain).